# Run a prnmngr.vbs as admin and pass variables to it from a VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, printing, vbscript

I have about 12 Wyse Thin Clients that need to have printers re-mapped everytime they log on. So I have an app that loads a mac/username/printermodel file then searches the registry for the mac of the Wyse client based on the user that logs in and passes the name of the printer, the printer driver and the port to use to prnmngr.vbs Which then installs the printer for the user.

The issue I'm having is unless I run the app as administrator the printer isn't added. Because prnmngr.vbs has to be run as an admin privlidge.

So how do I run prnmngr.vbs as admin and pass 3 variables to it?

George

Comment: This sounds like a job for AD group policy.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn The problem is that the port changes everytime the user logs in.

Comment: I know... but group policy can handle that per user and per device.

Comment: Do you have an article maybe? Everything I see has me setting up the port.

Comment: You want to make sure your printers are shared from a common print server, and then in GP Management when creating the policy look under User or Computer at Preferences->Control Panel->Printers

Comment: I forgot to mention that these are USB label printers not network printers. Each printer is attached to the Thin Client and when they log in I want it to attach to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, so bear with me. If you need to launch your app as administrator and prnmngr.vbs can inherit the permission then you could try this script.

```
 Option explicit
dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "runas /user:administrator ""yourapp.exe"""
WScript.Sleep 100
'Replace the string yourpassword~ below with
'the password used on your system. Include tilde 
oShell.Sendkeys "yourpassword~"
Wscript.Quit
```

Obviously you need to restrict reading of the script as it includes an admin password